# On rendering getting black screen in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

The code below is showing black screen even though body background color is #135462. I am thinking that its showing black screen due to rendering code. But not able to remove that black screen and getting the background color.

Object also is not displaying on the screen. My object link can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ukw7k1vyqkg4f7d/SupermanSmall.json?dl=0

Anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My three.js</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                background:#135462;
                color:#fff;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
                overflow:hidden;
                font-family:georgia;
                text-align:center;
            }


        </style>
    </head>

    <body>          

            <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/loaders/BinaryLoader.js"></script>

            <script src="js/loaders/ObjectLoader.js"></script>
            <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>

          <script>
          if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

                        var container;
            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {
                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 5;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.add( camera );

                var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
                loader.load( "obj/superman/SupermanSmall.json", function(obj){

                scene.add(obj);

                });

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );



            }

            function animate() {

                    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

                    renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

          </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: look at the javascript console messages. are there any errors there?

Comment: @ gaitat: "THREE.WebGLRenderer" "70" three.min.js:513:51
not well-formed SupermanSmall.json:1:1
TypeError: THREE[a.type] is not a constructor three.min.js:274:292. This is what I have in console.

Comment: thats why you get black screen. because you have errors in your code.

Comment: @kiran - it's good practice to look at the answers and upvote/accept them if they provided a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing that once you fix your errors you might still have a black screen. Try adding this:

```
renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE);
```

Or whatever color you want to put in there. You can also do this if you want:

```
renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xEEEEEE, 1.0));
```

This should change your background color.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to set the `alpha` property of the `renderer` to `true`. That will allow transparency to show the background you defined in the CSS, i.e.:

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(#e4e0ba, #f7d9aa);
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
// Create the renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```